# Drupal 9 - Two different URL's work for same page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-8, drupal-9

I have a **Drupal 9.x** version site, as an example whose page URL is like : http://www.example.com/general
but we need that URL to be work as http://www.example.com/something/general also.

It means, my every page of my site to be work (both URL's) **with** or **without** PRE-FIX word before of every page name.

***Reason:*** I am looking this feature is, my website page has to load into other website pages. Which means with an iframe I am planning to display the drupal 9.x content into other website. With this PREFIX word if we are calling the URL the header, footer, sidebar of the present page site will be hidden.

If with out the PREFIX word if i am looking the website, the header, footer, sidebar will be displayed normally.

> Both URLs should work:

I have about 550+ content pages, and many of our content pages are coming from custom modules, views.

I tried with URL alias, If i have go with this then I have to add these all 550+ content pages URL in our URL alias, that will not work for me.

Is there any other way around that i can achieve the same with minimum effort.

Please suggest me the solution, It will be very helpful for me.